# What are the implications of phase transition on electromagnetic device?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, classical-mechanics

for the analysis of ferromagnetic materials on which I confirmed existence of Phase transition using Monte Carlo simulation implemented on Mat lab. contribution to knowledge are required.

Comment: Can you be clearer - what is your actual question? Is it 'would a phase transition occurring be a problem in a functioning device?' than the answer is likely yes. But, what kind of a phase transition, in what kind of material, in what kind of application?

Comment: would a phase transition occurring in ferromagnetic materials be a problem in devices like space craft, air craft, Generator, Refrigerator? how?

Comment: Well, what is the function of the ferromagnetic material, and how will it change when it undergoes a phase change?

Comment: By the time magnetic materials undergo phase transitions, the technical systems in which they are being usually employed are long destroyed, so the answer is negative. Phase transition sensors are, on the other hand, being used to precisely define temperatures and in some cryogenic applications.

Comment: Thanks. ferromagnetic materials are magnetic materials that can be used in the production of some electromagnets like those mentioned above and they can exhibit some critical  phenomena e.g. phase transition which will result to magnetization reducing as temperature is increasing as confirmed by my research result shown .